# Set Response media type as either xml or json

Tags: java, json, xml

This is the code I am working with (someone else's project):

```
public class MyResponse

public static Response success(String content) {
        MyResponse aRsponse = response(content);
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(aRsponse.getContent()).build();
    }

public static MyResponse response(final String content) {
        return MyResponse.builder().content(content).build();
    }
```

The GET/POSTs that call the success method have `@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)`preceding them.

I have implemented some logic to determine if `content` is an XML or JSON and was thinking I'd pass that in as a param to success. So something like:

`public static Response success(String content, boolean isJson)`

Now I need to set the media type of the Response (with an if/else). I know I need something along the lines of `.type(MediaType.TEXT_XML);` but I can't seem to figure this out given the code that I have to work with and given the various examples and documentation I have found.

Any help or steering in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to change the code to: Response.type(MediaType.TEXT_XML).status(Status.OK).entity(aRsponse.getContent()).build(); and get "The method type(String) is undefined for the type Response".

Comment: Just a not problem related question. There is a special reason for all methods being static?

Comment: I am not sure why the methods are static. It's how the code came that I have to work with. I will try to figure that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are using JAX-RS, right?

Take a look at `Response` object documentation. You are looking for the `type` method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html

To set a different `MediaType`, your code would look like:

```
Response.status(Status.OK).type(MediaType.TEXT_XML).entity(aRsponse.getContent()).build();
```

When you write the code `Response.attribute`, you are using the [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). So, to change something into the new object that would be build, you have to use the appropriate method to set the value on the attribute for the new class.

Comment: Yeah I am using JAX-RS. I apologize for my ignorance, I'm new to this, but when using your code I am getting the error "The method type(String) is undefined for the type Response". I will take a look at the documentation that you linked. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, I didnt put the order of the parameters in the correct way. The code should work now.

Comment: Oh, that seems to have fixed it. Thank you very much! I'll further checkout the documentation to see if I can figure out the 'why' the order matters there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using JAXB/JAX-RS, and latest version, you don't need to worry about such things. Just return the objects and let the implementation handle the rest. No need to programmatically set media type or build.

eg.

```
@GET
@Path("/xmlexample")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public MyObject xml() {
  return new MyObject();
}

@GET
@Path("/jsonexample")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public MyObject json() {
  return new MyObject();
}
```

You just need to make sure your class has the right annotations eg. @XmlElement.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem, which I should have stated, is that the GET can get either a JSON or an XML, I don't know which. I then have to programmatically figure out which one and return a Response that is set to the right type.